# Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (86,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an excel sheet that contains a set of data (basically a few columns) and the last column called "Score" has the values (decimal i.e. 0.000 to 100.000) based on the previous columns. (27,000 rows in total)

What I am trying to achieve is to predict the score of new data, for that I am training my model with the excel sheet first.

```
set_random_seed(7)
dataframe = pd.read_excel('SS_Abcde.xlsx')

data = dataframe.iloc[:, 3:23]

labels_column = np.array(dataframe[['Score']])
print(labels_column.shape[0])


print("printing len of score", len(labels_column))

uniqueData = (np.unique(labels_column))
print("printing unique len of score", len(uniqueData))

labels_column = to_categorical(labels_column)
labels_column = [labels_column]

training_data = data
training_labels = labels_column


print("Start the training of the model")

model = Sequential()
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

print("model Fitting")
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs=5, verbose=1)
print("training has done")
```

But when I run this, it gives me Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (100,) but got array with shape (86,)
```

If I change this

```
model.add(Dense(100, activation='softmax'))
```

to this:

```
model.add(Dense(86, activation='softmax'))
```

It works, as in it starts the model training with the epochs defined. But why? why won't it work with Dense(100) instead? Isn't this the output layer?

EDIT:

Following @Reza Behzadpou, I normalized my complete dataset and a picture of that is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgH3K.png)

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

print("model Fitting")
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs=150, verbose=1)
print("training has done")

Xnew = np.array([[4.14854335054294e-21, 1, 1.36799259164156e-05, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5.44716062111488e-06, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

#Note that the above set of data already exists in the csv and its Score is 0.6137532, so I am assuming somewhat closer predication

ynew=model.predict(Xnew)
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
```

OUTPUT:

Instead of closer to 0.6137532 I am getting a predicted value of 1. instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H9HB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsgFd.png)

The method I used for normalizing the dataset

```
def GetNormalizedValue(val, min, max):
    if min == max:
        return 0
    denominator = max - min
    numerator = float(val) - min
    value = numerator / denominator
    return value
```

**EDIT 2:**

I even tried using it with MinMaxScaler() like:

```
dataset=np.loadtxt("SS_Munir_Updated.csv", delimiter=",")
x=dataset[:, 0:20]
y=dataset[:, 20]
y=np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
print(scaler.fit(x))
print(scaler.fit(y))
xscale=scaler.transform(x)
yscale=scaler.transform(y)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xscale, yscale)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150,  verbose=1)

Xnew = np.array([[0.00000000000000000000414854335054294, 1, 0.0000136799259164156, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                  0.00000544716062111488, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

ynew=model.predict(Xnew)
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
```

OUTPUT:

1.

Instead of anything closer to 0.6137532

Comment: First of all, I think you should solve it as a Regression problem, not a Classification one.

Comment: @parthagar would you please explain a little more? Thank you

Comment: https://www.datascience.com/blog/regression-and-classification-machine-learning-algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have 86 different values in your **score column** and for softmax layer to classify them, it needs 86 different neurons.

There're a couple of thing to note here:

- You have a **Regression** problem, but you're using a **softmax** layer to
  predict the score, which is used for **Classification** problems. use
  "**sigmoid**" instead.
- There's no normalization of your input data. You mentioned that your
  score values are between 0.0000 and 100.000, which is a huge range
  for Deep Learning Networks. Scale your dataset column values to be in
  the range of 0 to 1. **Encode** and **OneHotEncode** any String column in
  your dataset.

After normalizing your dataset, change your code as below:

> Change your output layer like this:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

> And compile the code as below:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I change this to regression model? Should I follow this approach isntead? https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

Comment: Encode and OneHotEncode any String column in your dataset <  Could you please explain how?

Comment: It depends on your column values. Show us an instance of your dataset.

Comment: I have made the changes and added the details in the Edited question, check please?

Comment: You don't have any String columns, so you there's no need for **LabelEncode** or **OneHotEncode**. But you still need to shift your dataset column range between 0 and 1. Use [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) or [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to achieve this.

Comment: I have already normalized my dataset using a custom Normalized method that changes the values between 0-1 but the problem is that it is not predicting a correct result like I mentioned in the question above, I gave the input from one of the dataset whose score was 0.6137532 but it predicted 1. instead

Comment: KIndly check Edit 2!

Comment: I don't have your dataset, so I can't test it myself. If it's possible, give us a link to the original dataset.